# Filtering BBCodes for certain elements

Tags: php, html, arrays, bbcode, str-replace

It's easy to explain what I want to achieve, but for me (a novice at PHP), hard to actually achieve it. Basically what I want is to make BBCodes as easily and short as possible. Instead of an array like

```
$filter=array(
    '[b]'=>'<b>',
    '[/b]'=>'</b>',
    '[i]'=>'<i>',
    '[/i]'=>'</i>');
```

I'd like to have this array:

```
$filter=array('b','i');
```

Then, the part I can't get to, would be where it checks for the strings in that array to have brackets around them (and, another thing I can't figure out, to be able to check also for `/` in the bracket) and then replace those brackets with `<>`. So, `[b]` would become `<b>` and `[/b]` would become `</b>`.

Edit: Solution

```
function bbcode($string) {
    $filter=array('b','i','u');
    foreach ($filter as $filter) {
        $string=str_replace('['.$filter.']','<'.$filter.'>',$string);
        $string=str_replace('[/'.$filter.']','</'.$filter.'>',$string);
        }
    return $string;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filter = array('b','i');

$newfilter = array();
foreach ($filter as $tag) {
  $newfilter["[$tag]"] = "<$tag>";
  $newfilter["[/$tag]"] = "</$tag>";
}
```

Now you can use `$newfilter`.

Comment: I prefer not to make unnecessary arrays, but that code did help me to make something that works for me. Thanks. I'll put the code in the first post for anyone who may want it.

Comment: Cheers and thanks for the accept.  You don't actually need to copy the code, though, as this answer will always be here. ;)